# share option with new version of tweeter

Tags: javascript, jquery

The tweeter sharing option on my site with twitter old version is working fine. but with new version it puts plus sign between words. I already used Server.Urlencode method to encode the string. With New version of tweeter url becomes

```
http://twitter.com/#!/?status=Contribute+to+GeoInvesting+Board+-+Ask+Bob+-+GEO%27s+PRC+Attorney+http%3A%2F%2Fsafe.mn%2F36Yx+%24%24
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

use

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=status
```

instead of using

```
http://twitter.com/home/?status=status
```

Hope this will help someone.